# how get search:suggestion from multiple range elements source as default-suggestion-source option

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

xml sample like below in my MarkLogic database

```
<metadata>
      <title>first title</title>
      <author>gorge k</author>
      <location>London</location>
</metadata>
```

I have a range index set up on `title`, `author` and `location`. I want to create default search:suggestion source on all elements instead of any single element.

In search:option I have only title as default suggestion source option as below

```
<default-suggestion-source>
  <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/" 
      type="xs:string">
    <element ns="" name="title"/>
  </range>
</default-suggestion-source>
```

Now I want to add both `author` and `location` in above default suggestion source option.

I try to add `author` using this configuration:

```
<default-suggestion-source>
  <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/" 
      type="xs:string">
    <element ns="" name="title"/>
  </range>
  <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/" 
      type="xs:string">
    <element ns="" name="author"/>
  </range>
</default-suggestion-source>
```

but am getting below error:

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-ARGTYPE: (err:XPTY0004) fn:string((attribute{fn:QName("","collation")}{"http://marklogic.com/collation/"}, attribute{fn:QName("","collation")}{"http://marklogic.com/collation/"})) -- arg1 is not of type item()?

Any one please suggest how achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a suggestion source to [refer to a constraint](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/appendixb#id_85882). You can set up a constraint to be a [field, based on the three elements you're interested in](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields#chapter). Set up a field range index and search options like below, and I think that should work.

```
<search:options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <constraint name="suggestions">
    <range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/">
      <field name="suggest-field"/>
    </range>
  </constraint>
  <default-suggestion-source ref="suggestions" />
</search:options>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave for above suggestion. I set up field and range-field-index, now its working.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dave Cassel's solution, i would suggest not referencing the `default-suggestion-source` to a constraint. Rather include the constraint in the `default-suggestion-source` node.

```
<search:options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <default-suggestion-source>
    <range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/">
      <field name="suggest-field"/>
    </range>
  </default-suggestion-source>
</search:options>
```

Why? MarkLogic will not only suggest values found in the source (range index in this case) but also **constraint names**. So you will have a suggestion `suggestions:`. This might not be wanted for the default source.

For further reading see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54163596/3523756).