# MarkLogic "search:suggest" finds constraint name

Tags: marklogic

So this one is really weird. I have a completly **empty database** and use the following code:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
    at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:suggest("qwe" , 
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <constraint name="qweqwe">
      <word type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/">
        <element name="test"/>
      </word>
    </constraint>
    <default-suggestion-source ref="qweqwe"/>
  </options>
)
```

The result of this is one suggestions: `qweqwe:`

The `search:suggest` seems to find the **constraint name** and suggest it.

Steps to reproduce:

- clear database
- create element word lexicons for element `test` with collation `http://marklogic.com/collation/`
- execute previous code

Using ml 9.0-8 with a completly empty and reindexed `documents` database. You can change the name of the constraint to whatever you want, you can always get a suggestion for it. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a bug, it is by design. [`search:suggest`](https://docs.marklogic.com/search:suggest), and [`/v1/suggest`](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/suggest) are most commonly used for typeahead suggestions in a search bar. It is a user-convenience kind of thing. It helps the user discover the available constraints, giving them back including a colon, so you can continue looking for values for that constraint, after inserting the name+colon.

HTH!

Comment: OK i see. But does this make sense for default-suggestion-source? Why would i search for the constraint referenced to it?

Comment: It always does suggestions for everything it knows, so default suggestions, constraint names, and where appropriate also constraint values (if you happen to use a constraint prefix).. consider dropping the constraint, and just putting a `word-lexicon` inside the `default-suggestion-source` element..

Comment: Did not know about that feature, but i actually really like the idea. Dropping the constraint is what i did. Thank you!